# Touching two phones together to send data

Tags: mobile, touch, bump

I'm trying to develop an application like Bump to receive data from another device by touching them together. I could not find any tutorial on Google about this. Can somebody help me make an idea about how this works? What programming language should I use, how can I do it by using Bluetooth or/and Wifi, etc? I only need some info. I don't know where to start. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create something like bump for iPhone, you could code it in Objective-C or swift. (Based on preference) For android you would code it in Java. To make this bump you need to create a trigger that detects a shake gesture on the device to trigger additional code. The additional code will take the location and the time of both devices in the bump and save it into a database. You need to check the location and the timestamp and compare those values. If is the same location and at the same time you know those are the two devices in the bump. After you know the devices involved you can send whatever information between those devices. Hope this helped.